# Как в ViewPager сделать частично видимыми соседние страницы?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У `ViewPager` по бокам видны другие Pagers. Как сделать так в Android? Может есть библиотека какая нибудь? Или можно стандартными средствами сделать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чтобы сделать частично видимыми соседние страницы:

```
viewpager.setClipToPadding(false);
viewpager.setPadding(64, 0, 64, 0);
```

Чтобы добавить пустоты между страницами:

```
viewpager.setPageMargin(32);
```

Comment: Есть только одно но. Соседние страницы при верстке xml. Releative внутри не работает. Я хотел сделать margintop 10dp от Top картинки. А она накладывается от края верхней части экрана. align не работает

Comment: Попробуйте вместо нуля поставить какие-то значения здесь `viewpager.setPadding(64, **0**, 64, 0);`